# GZIP compression on HTTPS traffic security issue with BREACH/CRIME attacK?

Tags: security, ssl, webserver

For example when I have a look on the HTTP header of https://www.facebook.com I see that they utilize GZIP compression **Content-Encoding: gzip** with SSL/TLS traffic.

Isn't that a bad idea because of BREACH/CRIME attack?

```
curl -I -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate' https://www.facebook.com
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Expires: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15552000; preload
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Fri, 15 May 2015 18:56:11 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 15101
```

According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BREACH_%28security_exploit%29

Comment: I suggest reading https://community.qualys.com/blogs/securitylabs/2013/08/07/defending-against-the-breach-attack

Answer (score 17, accepted):

BREACH exists when you have TLS plus HTTP compression (ie gzip). But it also requires:

1. useful, secret information in the response body
2. attacker must be able to inject a value into the response body with a request parameter
3. no random response padding

Comments:

1. Hackers are after credit card numbers, passwords, CSRF tokens, and probably not chats with your GF, but you never know.
2. It looks like a lot of the input responses (search bar at top, for example) are out-of-band, ie the response is over AJAX so doesn't affect other responses.
3. Facebook might be padding their responses, but I haven't delved too deeply into that.