# How can I use gzip with SSL, or any alternatives?

Tags: ssl, gzip

Google now treats HTTP as insecure (check [here](http://www.pcworld.com/article/3118164/security/google-chrome-to-start-marking-http-connections-as-insecure.html)), and in Chrome, we see warning messages if we access HTTP site. And now we have free SSL, letsencrypt. So I assume, we would surely use HTTPS for nearly every server.

Then I found, using gzip with SSL has some security issue, called Breach Attack. I really wonder, then, how can we achieve  the purpose of gzip, while using SSL?

Especially on Angular, when built, it has quite large sizes; for now, I have main files that related to @angular, styles files that related to CSS/SCSS/whatever bundled with Webpack, scripts files that related to external javascript files. For my application case, it is like below (Angular 2.3.1, AoT, production build);

- main.js: 739K
- main.js.gz: 151K
- styles.js: 394K
- styles.js.gz: 100K
- scripts.js: 1.8M
- scripts.js.gz: 415K

For main and styles file, it seems okay without gzip. But for scripts file case, it is really big without gzip. 1.8 Megabytes... it would definitely heavy for mobile.

But my application uses WebRTC, which requires HTTPS. So it's kind of stuck for me. Is there any good solution?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30266931/gzip-compression-on-https-traffic-security-issue-with-breach-crime-attack

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BREACH attack is only a problem for content which contains secrets the attacker likes to guess (like CSRF tokens) and where also attacker controlled data are reflected in the content. Static Javascript files and other static files don't have this property so they can safely be compressed. See also [Is gzipping content via TLS allowed?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/102013/is-gzipping-content-via-tls-allowed) or [Current State of BREACH (GZIP SSL Attack)?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/65625/current-state-of-breach-gzip-ssl-attack)